# Google Chrome Sync extension preference

Tags: google-chrome, sync, google-chrome-extensions

In `Chrome`, it's possible to sync extensions, but is it possible to also sync extensions' preferences?

For example, if I add a manual rule into `AdBlock`, is it possible to sync that manual rule along with my account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an extension uses [chrome.storage.sync](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html) for saving user preferences (like the filters or rules of Adblock Plus), it should get synchronized.